# Spring java config with JTA transaction

Tags: java, spring, jta

I writing a simple project in Spring and I want use JTA transaction. I want to java class base config, not xml. I search in Internet good configuration, but I don't find any interesting tutorial. My config class:

```
    package pl.airlines.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("pl.airlines")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
        return new JtaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("pl.airlines.model");

        factory.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup jndiDataSourceLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        return jndiDataSourceLookup.getDataSource("java:app/jdbc/airlinesDS");
    }

}
```

When i start my application i get following warnings:

```
  WARN:   HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
Info:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: pl.piotr_Airlines_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU
    ...]
Info:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
Info:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Info:   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Info:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Info:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Warning:   Exception while dispatching an event
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.getStatus(JtaStatusHelper.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.JtaStatusHelper.isActive(JtaStatusHelper.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jta.CMTTransaction.join(CMTTransaction.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.postInit(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.internalCreateEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:345)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:313)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$2.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:451)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.iterateInitializedPUsAtApplicationPrepare(JPADeployer.java:492)
    at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.event(JPADeployer.java:398)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.ReDeployCommand.execute(ReDeployCommand.java:131)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [pl.airlines.configuration.WebAppInitializer@6fec3758]
Info:   Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) for context '/Airlines'
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Severe:   log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
Severe:   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Info:   WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
Info:   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Info:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Info:   HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Info:   HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Info:   HHH000396: Updating schema
Info:   HHH000261: Table found: HR.USERS
Info:   HHH000037: Columns: [password, firstname, personalid, address, city, phone, id, email, username, lastname]
Info:   HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
Info:   HHH000126: Indexes: [sys_c009172, sys_c009173]
Info:   HHH000232: Schema update complete
Info:   Loading application [Airlines] at [/Airlines]
Info:   Airlines was successfully deployed in 11 992 milliseconds.
```

My persistence.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="pl.piotr_Airlines_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/airlinesDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>

    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

How configure spring with JTA? Above code is not good, because when I try persist with simple method

```
    @Transactional
public void add() {
    User user = new User();
    user.setId(1L);
    user.setUsername("Jan");
    user.setPassword("abcd");
    entityManager.persist(user);
}
```

User not saved.
Anybody have a good example JTA configuration with Spring? Of course I mean Java class based configuration.

Comment: you should use `entityManager.merge(user)`

Comment: That's not problem. I need a good configuration.

Comment: Do you have `persistence.xml` file?

Comment: Yes. I added in first post.

Comment: In `persistanc.xml` you are using `<jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/myDatasource</jta-data-source>` and in code `java:app/jdbc/airlinesDS`  why?

Comment: I have open many projects. I copy wrong persistence.xml Sorry. I update post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96914/discussion-between-bilal-shah-and-the-nightmare).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this property `<property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>` in persistence.xml file.