# Spring Data JPA transaction custom isolation level

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Given the following scenario:
I have an app running with Spring Boot `@SpringBootApplication` and setup with Spring Data JPA datasource in `application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://foo.bar.com:12345
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and no additional java/xml configs.

I have a couple of services:

```
@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public Project save(Project project) {
        // there might be some additional logic here, besides the action on repository
        return projectRepository.save(project);
    }
}
```

and repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectRepository extends CrudRepository<Project, Long> {}
```

As it's in the code above, I found myself in need of, let's say, `SERIALIZABLE` level of isolation due to the app being scaled up horizontally and occasionally saving conflicting data to DB (simply `@Transactional` was no enough). Now, when trying I try to perform `projectService.save(project)` action I get an exception:

```
"exception": "org.springframework.transaction.InvalidIsolationLevelException",
"message": "JtaTransactionManager does not support custom isolation levels by default - switch 'allowCustomIsolationLevels' to 'true'",
```

Is it possible to enable those custom isolation levels with a java config?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable `allowCustomIsolationLevels` by setting below in `TransactionManager`

```
transactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
```

Comment: My question was refering more to the fact that I do not know how to access `tramsactionManager` to be able to set that value. Can it be done somehow with `@EnableTransactionManagement`?

Comment: You will be defining a transactionManager in applicationcontext.xml or some other xml file.  Please set <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true"/> in the bean definition of transactionManager.

Comment: the case is I do not use xml-based spring configuration. Is it possible to be done with java config?

Comment: Yes . http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072965/spring-java-config-with-jta-transaction

Comment: I tried to do:
 `@Configuration
 public class TransactionConfig {
 
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager) {
   jtaTransactionManager.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
   return jtaTransactionManager;
  }
 }`

but it fails to run. Is ther something that I'm missing?

Comment: @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager platformTransactionManager() {
        return new JtaTransactionManager();
    }

Comment: I did as you advised. Now when doing any action I'm getting `Error while committing the transaction ... Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed ... Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection ... Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You cannot commit with autocommit set!` while having `spring.datasource.auto-commit=false`. I found out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26637847/spring4-hibernate4-jta-write-operations-fail) that hibernate might not be aware of WildFly JTA active transcation manager. Can that be right?

Answer (score 0):

my stack: Java 17, Spring Boot 3.0.6, Hibernate 6.2.5.Final, WildFly 28.0.1

Worked for me:

```
@Configuration
public class TransactionConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    public TransactionConfiguration(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        JtaTransactionManager jta = (JtaTransactionManager) transactionManager;
        jta.setAllowCustomIsolationLevels(true);
    }
}
```